# OpenGL Render Queue - Where do my buffers go?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, rendering, game-engine

I'm trying to redesign my current rendering system, which pretty much works as you would think for a first time renderer: Every frame, the game calls Render(), which calls Render() on the world, which Z sorts the entities (It's a 2D game), calls Render(SpriteBatch& batch) on every Entity, and then each Entity uses the given SpriteBatch to render it's sprite. The SpriteBatch has a VAO, a VBO, and an EBO. It is efficient for sprite rendering, but still fairly naive. I also have no way to render other things, like polygons and lines and such. For example, I wanted to be able to just tell my renderer to render a line from one point to another. In order to do that now, I have to create an entire Mesh, set its primitive type to GL_LINES, upload vertex data, upload element data, then call Render() on it somewhere. And those lines won't even be batched because they each have their own OpenGL buffers.

I want to move all the rendering logic into my OpenGLRenderer class. I have been doing lots of reading and it seems like the way to go is to use some sort of RenderQueue and RenderCommand setup. I think I understand that pretty well - Each entity will create a RenderCommand, with its Mesh/Material or Sprite (which would just be data) and then submit it to the Renderer. The Renderer will then sort the commands based on Material and such to avoid state changes wherever possible.

This is where my question comes in. Where will my buffers go? I have an entire queue of RenderCommands, which point to all the vertex and material data I need, but how do I get this over to OpenGL? I was thinking about just having one big VAO, VBO, and EBO, and treating the entire thing like a big batch. I would flush the buffers if state needed to change, and batch data together that could be batched. However something feels strange about having one huge set of OpenGL buffers for an entire game.

Comment: This is more of a decision decision, I think. I'm currently writing a rendering system very similar to the one you're saying isn't sufficient; the goal of which is to expose underlying functionality more readily to its users. However, I will point out your "one big buffer" is actually the way the winds are blowing. Look up "Approaching Zero Driver Overhead" and how things are done in Vulkan. That said, the design you mention first and such a model for buffer management are not mutually exclusive (which again, I know first hand).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "mutually exclusive". Could you explain?

Comment: Well, your current design of having more involved, direct-access-ish classes vs. a wrapper/polymorhpic/generalized RenderCommand class --- multiple distinct buffers vs. one single partitioned buffer. You can really mix either option with either of the others; for example, you could have very raw rendering classes that are given segments of a single engine buffer, which is a design I am implementing.

Comment: But the end point of what I was getting at is, the new design you're talking about is actually already very well documented and in use by Vulkan and I suggest you look into the specifics of that. It does have some issues, though. One is you effectively have to manage your own memory within that single buffer - and prevent the horror the OS usually does for you (with the help of the memory access hardware): memory fragmentation. It's not a small task. Vulkan, FYI, is basically the next OpenGL.

Comment: Sounds good. Vulkan seems really huge and complex so I'm not really sure where I would get started looking at that stuff.

Comment: In the best-case, nowhere. They should all be server-side (GPU) data that are not touched every frame. For most applications, anything you keep CPU-side should just be a reference to GPU data or data waiting to be uploaded.

Comment: @Dooskington It's very badly documented (beyond the standard, which is not exactly documentation) since it just released. Like I mentioned, you might also look at "Approaching Zero Driver Overhead" stuff, as it discusses the data model being applied in OpenGL, which might make it simpler.

Comment: I wrote a longish answer but I realized there's no defined question here, and that you seem to be aware of the implications of state changes in OpenGL. Anyway, I just want to remind you that your application is just a client, and you interact with a server. You don't need to know how the server manages the data; it can be on RAM, on the GPU, on a different machine in a different country. You keep references to that data and nothing more. It's greatly implementation-dependent. It does not matter.
Your approach with a rendering queue is correct. Go with it. No question to answer here.

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys.